# Separate admin and public-facing search with Haystack/Django/Solr

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

My site has items which can be published or unpublished. Unpublished items should not show up on the frontend but should appear in the backend (I am not using the Django admin).

I have an ArticleIndex with a `get_queryset` method which returns `Article.published.all()` (`published` is a custom manager which only deals with published articles).

How should I implement a second index of all the items (including unpublished) for use in the admin interface? This is mentioned in the release announcement of Haystack 2.0 (see the [homepage](http://haystacksearch.org/)) but the docs only describe a master/slave setup using two separate search engines, which seems like overkill for this?!

Answer (score 0):

Found this question by encountering the same problem and search.
There are <strike>three</strike> two ways of separating searches.

- Using QuerySets:
  https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html
- Creating a separate Solr Core for each search type.

<strike>and a secret third - 
backend switching</strike> (totally unsafe, experimental and error-prone)